# Need to draw a Node-Edges Chart within GeneXus

Tags: javascript, charts, user-controls, genexus

i need to **draw a node-edges** chart within GeneXus Evo2 U5 to show relationships between an **Balanced-Scorecard** application's objectives and perspectives.

Someone knows about any JS library to make this work in a simple way?

I think is similar to tables relations diagram from GeneXus.

[image: HHRR Strategy Map]

[image: Typical Strategic Map Chart]

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) in a GeneXus Project to show simple relationships. See more information in t[his article (spanish)](http://ealmeida.blogspot.com/2008/08/agregar-imagenes-de-grafos-aplicaciones.html)

To manage more complex graph I use [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) and [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/), but are more difficult to use.

Comment: Thank you Enrique! I have used **graphviz** following your previous indications but i need more interactivity and control (i need it to graph an **Strategic Map**)

Comment: Oh! **Please**, give me an example with **D3** working into GeneXus!

I need _so much_ to build this graph in my application because resume a general idea from data.

Thank you in advance!